# WooCommerce Product Attribute Terms Description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

As stated in the title I have the following code & just need the term_id within the second foreach which will return what I want. I have used 38 which is a valid id but it needs to be the term_id that has the same $meta-key which is the taxonomy slug like pa_some-product-attribute-term

```
    function get_order_details($order_id){

      $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

      foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

        //$product = $item->get_product();

        foreach ( $item->get_formatted_meta_data() as $meta_id => $meta ) {
          print_r($meta->display_key);
          echo '<br>';
          print_r($meta->display_value);
          echo '<br>';
          print_r(term_description(38, $meta->key));
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: get_term_by() function heps you... https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Comment: I have tried that but returns nothing, the actual table in the database is wp_term_taxonomy and the column is taxonomy which contains pa_some-product-attribute-term

Comment: Have you tried this... get_term_by('slug','pa_some-product-attribute-term','wp_term_taxonomy');

Comment: That returns false also, it works if I use get_term_by('term_taxonomy_id', 38) using the id, but I want the id

Comment: Have you tried the get_term() method.,

Comment: Yes I have tried that also